# WCF Service - Automatically call method with worker thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

I have a very simple WCF Service that works as a calculator that only adds two numbers.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "Calculating")]
public interface ICalculator
{
    [OperationContract]
    double Add(double n1, double n2);
}

// Implementation of the ICalculator interface.
public class CalculatorServer : ICalculator
{
    public double Add(double n1, double n2)
    {
        double result = n1 + n2;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Likewise, I have a very simple WCF client that calls the Calculator interface using `ChannelFactory`.

```
var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service");
var factory = new ChannelFactory<ICalculator>(new WSHttpBinding(), endpointAddress);
ICalculator proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

Console.WriteLine(proxy.Add(5, 3));

factory.Close();
```

This code works fine, however I am currently struggling with creating a method that will automatically be called by the interface using a worker thread once the service starts. What I wanted to do was that, while the main thread is recieving requests for the calculator, the worker thread will print a message every five seconds. So I tried adding a contructor to my interface implementation that would call this method:

```
private bool isAlive;

public CalculatorServer()
{
   isAlive = true;
   // Queue the main service function for execution in a worker thread.
   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ServiceWorkerThread), isAlive);
}

private void ServiceWorkerThread(object state)
{
    isAlive = (bool)state;

    // Periodically check if the service is stopping.
    while (this.isAlive)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("This is a message!");
         Thread.Sleep(5000); // sleep for five seconds
    }
}
```

But when I run my client the message doesn't display. At first I thought it was because the constructor was not being called for some reason, but after initializing a `double` and later using it in the `Add` method I know for a fact this is not the case. So what am I doing wrong? Bear in mind that I'm still fairly new to WCF and multithreading.

Comment: Why would anything from the server print on the client? In fact, why would it print on the server? It's running a service - there is no console.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Then which would be the right way to achieve something like this? All I want is that while the service is taking requests from the client, at the same time it's automatically doing something else - be it printing a message, or writing on a file, etc.

Comment: I would first of all suggest that you use a _separate_ service. Maybe just a small Windows Service. This is called separation of concerns. Let the web service be a web service, handling requests from the clients. Write something else to perform background operations. But operations on the server do not, in general, interact with the clients, unless the clients have made a request.

Comment: That said, there is a technology called SignalR which permits service code to "push" things to client code. You could look into that, but I suggest you first correct your understanding of how web services, and the web, actually work in the general case.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I don't actually want to interact with the client, I had only wanted to use a simple example that I could *see* was working. So even if I don't interact with a them (suppose that I want a service that recieves e-mail messages from clients, and queues them on a DB, while at the same time the service checks the DB every 30 minutes or so to see if there are any emails pending to be sent automatically), should I use *two* services to achieve something like this?

Comment: Yes, you can use a WCF service to receive calls from the clients, and a normal Windows service to do anything else. They sound scary, but they've very easy to implement with Visual Studio. Just override a couple of methods.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I'll look into that then. Also, out of curiosity, is implementing that scenario possible with just a WCF service? Since my boss was insistent that I used threads.

Comment: It's not a best practice. The WCF service is meant for request/response scenarios, not for long-running tasks.